# Dynamic localization in vue-i18n

Tags: internationalization, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I would like to update my localization messages in vue-i18n dynamically.

I am building a webshop, where every item has descriptions in more languages. So what I’d like to achieve is when I get the webshop items from the REST API I want to put their names, descriptions etc. to the messages object in vue-i18n so it can work with them. Does the vue-i18n API have something to handle that? Also I am getting the data from the server (I get a Promise), so how can I make sure it gets updated in the browser view, when I finally get the response, and add the data to the localization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was write a mixin, and use it everywhere I need dynamic localization:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    $t: function (translate) {
      if (typeof translate === 'string') {
        return this.$i18n.t(translate)
      } else if (translate === void 0) {
        return this.$i18n.t('loading')
      }
      return translate[this.$i18n.locale]
    }
  }
}
```

This way when my texts look like the following, I can call `$t(text)` (**NOT** `$t('text')` of course):

```
data: function () {
   return {text: {en:'Book', de:'Buch', hu:'Könyv'}}
}
```

So in your components you have to import this and add it as a mixin:

```
import dynamicLocalization from '@/components/mixins/dynamic-localization'

export default {
   ...
   mixins:[dynamicLocalization]
   ...
}
```